# How to save users theme selection when switching to another page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have two stylesheets - one for a dark theme that is the default, and the other for a light theme. I'm trying to figure out how to use localStorage to save the stylesheet selection when the user navigates to a new page. My code is quite simple:

Within the HTML, I set the ID in the stylesheet link tag in the head, and then the following is what I use to create the toggle:

```
<link href="/style.css" rel="stylesheet" id="theme-link">

<label class="switch">
            <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox">
            <span class="themeToggle toggle-thumb">
            </span>
       </label>
```

Here is the JS:

```
const btn = document.querySelector(".themeToggle");
let theme = document.querySelector("#theme-link");
btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  // Swap out the URL for the different stylesheets
  if (theme.getAttribute("href") == "/style.css") {
    theme.href = "/light-theme.css";
  } else {
    theme.href = "/style.css";
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can Store Variables In Local Storage like this:

`localStorage.setItem("selectedTheme", "light");`

`localStorage.setItem("selectedTheme", "dark");`

You can Get Variables From Local Storage like this:

`localStorage.getItem("selectedTheme");`

Source
https://www.w3schools.com/jsreF/prop_win_localstorage.asp